# Patching a Mach-O Binary Header to remove a LC_SEGMENT

Tags: binary-analysis, arm, patching, mach-o

i have an ARMv7 Mach-O Executable on which I want to patch out a certain segment in the binary header which prevents DYLD injection.

more information [here](http://www.samdmarshall.com/blog/blocking_code_injection_on_ios_and_os_x.html) under point 3. of preventing dyld injection. TL;DR a  __RESTRICT binary header section with a __restrict segment prevents DYLD injection on iOS.

Unfornatunately i'm not sure howto patch the file properly. Do I simply fill the file offset responsible for the LC_SEGMENT with zeros or do I remove it altogether (meaning cutting out and therefore altering file size and probably? breaking offsets)?

Thanks in advance

Malte

Answer (score 2):

[This tool](https://github.com/Tyilo/macho_edit) claims it can move and remove load commands. Might be worth a look.

Comment: The interface for this tool is somewhat clumsy, but I was able to remove a segment, but it does not update "relocation bytecodes". In my binary the bytecodes still referenced the removed segment after removal.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
Many years later I finally got a mac and can confirm @igors comments - it does not work for mac (:
Keeping this here for reference on how to achieve on Linux

Stripping a section from an ELF file is easy enough using the 'strip' command in any Linux (I'd bet in OSX too, though I never tried it myself).

Just do:

```
strip -R __restrict
```

It should do the trick

Comment: the question is about Mach-O, not ELF. OS X `strip` does no do section removal.

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky plain wrong. See man page here (http://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/strip/) and -R parameter here: `-R filename
       Remove the symbol table entries for the global symbols listed  in  filename.   This
       file  has  the same format as the -s filename option above.  This option is usually
       used in combination with other options that save some symbols, -S, -x, etc.`

Comment: Also check out the -c flag

Comment: Just as you quoted,  `-R` removes symbols, not sections (this is not GNU strip). As for, `-c`, while it does remove sections, the resulting file can be only used for linking (and you can't specify what to remove). Perhaps I should have said "does not do user-specified section removal".

Comment: Igor is right, Apple's `strip` can't remove sections. `-R` removes symbols and `-c` removes *all* sections (if I'm reading it right).

Comment: Although this doesn't address the question from OP, I found this helpful because I am also interested in doing this for Linux.